# OpenRefine reconciliation service not working - mutliple vs single queries

Tags: freebase, openrefine

I have been using OpenRefine 2.6 Beta 1 w/o problems since its release, and later, with the reconciliation service at:

http://reconcile.freebaseapps.com/reconcile

However, in the past fee days, I have not been able to use it all. If I go to the URL:

http://reconcile.freebaseapps.com/

and type the multiple query:

```
{
  "query": "Ford",
  "type": "/people/person",
  "properties": [
    {
      "pid": "/people/person/place_of_birth",
      "v": "Detroit"
    }
  ]
}
```

I obtain:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "/m/0j8pb6y",
      "name": "Ford",
      "type": [
        {
          "id": "/people/person",
          "name": "Person"
        },
        {
          "id": "/common/topic",
          "name": "Topic"
        },
        {
          "id": "/geography/mountaineer",
          "name": "Mountaineer"
        }
      ],
      "notable": [],
      "score": 1.1546246,
      "match": false
    },
    {
      "id": "/m/01vd3gv",
      "name": "Ford",
      "type": [
        {
          "id": "/common/topic",
          "name": "Topic"
        },
        {
          "id": "/music/artist",
          "name": "Musical Artist"
        }
      ],
      "notable": [],
      "score": 1.0330245999999998,
      "match": false
    },
    {
      "id": "/m/0cmdhzt",
      "name": "James Meredith",
      "type": [
        {
          "id": "/common/topic",
          "name": "Topic"
        },
        {
          "id": "/people/person",
          "name": "Person"
        },
        {
          "id": "/military/military_person",
          "name": "Military Person"
        },
        {
          "id": "/people/deceased_person",
          "name": "Deceased Person"
        }
      ],
      "notable": [],
      "score": 0.0681692,
      "match": false
    }
  ],
  "duration": 369
}
```

But if I try a simple query:

```
{
  "query": "Ford"
}
```

I get:

```
Status: error Error:undefined
```

Any insights into what's happening with the reconciliation service? Is there any other service I could use to replace freebaseapps.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in **Queries Parameter** at http://reconcile.freebaseapps.com/

```
{
  "q0": {
    "query": "Ford"
  }

}
```

For some reason, single queries are not accepted in **Query Parameter** but in **Queries Parameter** in the format above. I have not tested this in OpenRefine, so you might have to modify it.

Comment: Thank you. I copied and pasted the solution in Queries Parameter and works well, but it still does not work in OpenRefine 2.6. I documented the issues in Open Refine's GitHub. They changed to 2.6-rc2, I'll try that next.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for certain about the date, but Freebase was announced earlier this year as being shutdown by Jun 30, 2015, for some services. Maybe service is intermittent until full shutdown? Sorry, this answer probably doesn't help much.

Comment: Thank you, but freebaseapps.com had been working fine since freebase shutdown, and it is not part of Google's freebase

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I assumed freebaseapps.com was part of the services being shut down. Were you able to figure out what happened?

Comment: Thank you. No, I don't know what's going on. Maybe @magdmartin knows what's happening?